# joomla 1.5 search integration with custom components?

Tags: search, joomla, components, joomla1.5

Does anyone know how to integrate the joomla search functionality with customly built components? Or know of a tutorial/information page with the information I'd need?

I'd like the search to pickup information from my components, currently it's only returning data from articles, web links, contacts, categories, sections and news feeds. I have a few custom components which I need the search to find results in.

If anyone could help, that would be great! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you need to write a search plugin for each component that you want to extend the search to. There is a good tutorial here -
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_search_plugin